# returning empty array from post request

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am trying to pass some dynamic values from my form, but so far I am only getting empty values. 
I have an autocomplete plugin, where I search for "names" from a JSON object, each time I select one they will pass into a list with `value="the ID"`.

I couldn't find a unordered list in `WTForms`, so I am using `SelectMultipleField` instead, since it is able to pass many values as an array/list

my form class is looking like this:

```
class ClassForm(Form):
    function_name      = StringField('names')
    studentid          = SelectMultipleField('studentid')
    submit             = SubmitField('submit')
```

then in my template I am using it like this

```
<form id="function_search_form" method="post" action="">
  {{ form.csrf_token }}

  {{form.function_name.label()}}
  {{form.function_name()}}

  <!-- then I am not using studentid directly, 
       but just normal html, so each time you pass 
       in a name from the json object it will come in like this. 
  -->
 <ol class='student-list'>
    <li value="1" name="studentid" id="studentid">test</li>
 </ol>

 {{ form.submit()}}
</form>
```

My problem is that it wont get the value from the list, even if I hard code the values directly, instead from the jquery script.

Here is how my view looks like

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = ClassForm()
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
        flash('valid form')
        st = form.studentid.data
        print(st)#debug
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

Everytime I submit I am printing `form.studentid.data` I am getting `[]`, which is an empty list.

Even when I try to pass single values and make `studentid` to a `StringField` I am still getting an empty value.

I have also tried the `request.form['studentid']` but then I am getting **Bad Request** What am I doing wrong and is there another way to pass "custom" values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason its not working is because `<li>` is not a form control, so its data is not sent back with the form request.

You are never rendering the `studentid` field from your form class, so the form control is never rendered.  It would be like expecting the following to work:

```
<form>
   <p name="foo" data="hello">This should be sent</p>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

To get the data back to your view method, you need to use a form control - you can test it out like this:

```
<form id="function_search_form" method="post" action="">
  {{ form.csrf_token }}

  {{form.function_name.label()}}
  {{form.function_name()}}

  <select name="studentid" class='student-list'>
    <option value="1">test</option>
  </select>

 {{ form.submit()}}
</form>
```

Or, simply render the field correctly:

```
<form id="function_search_form" method="post" action="">
  {{ form.csrf_token }}

  {{form.function_name.label()}}
  {{form.function_name()}}
  {{form.studentid.label()}}
  {{form.studentid}}

  {{ form.submit()}}
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Burhan, yes you are indeed right with `<li>` not being sent back within the form request. But then I am facing this new problem if that isn't possible. Because I need to send an array back with their values(their ID's) and it needs to be listed as a `<li>` or some kind of something similar. A checkbox or a multiple-select box won't work because you will not be able to click "remove this" from the list. I have been looking at `WTForms` - 'FieldList', but with no success.

Comment: For example if you look at WTforms [link](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.2/widgets.html) you can see that they can indeed render the field as a `ul-li` with `ListWidget(html_tag=u'ul', prefix_label=True)`

Comment: From the documentation you have linked. _"Renders a list of fields as a ul or ol list."_ - it will render a **list of fields**, not a field. Its just a shortcut to create a loop of form fields. You pass it a list of fields, it will render each field in an encapsulated ordered or unordered list. The fields themeselves will be form fields, like a check box or a radio button.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thanks Burhan. I found a little solution/hack on how to fix this. Instead of using checkboxes I am using `input="hidden"` to get the value and then populate the data as a normal list. Thanks again for the help.